# zsh prompt not escaped properly

Tags: zsh, prompt

This is my current prompt definition:

```
PROMPT='%(?..%F{red}%?%f:)%F{blue}%n%f:%F{green}%{${PWD/#$HOME/~}%} %(!.%F{red}.%f)%# %f'
```

The cursor sometimes starts one character behind the actual prompt, for example when searching the history using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the `%{` and `%}` from around the part of the PROMPT that prints the working directory.

```
PROMPT='%(?..%F{red}%?%f:)%F{blue}%n%f:%F{green}${PWD/#$HOME/~} %(!.%F{red}.%f)%# %f'
```

The `%{` and `%}` sequences are meant to be placed around bits of the prompt that do not affect the position of the cursor (e.g. a hard-coded control sequence). By surround something that actually moves the cursor (by printing your current working directory), you are confusing *zsh*’s notion of where the cursor is; when it needs to redraw part of the current line (e.g. when you use C-r to search), it ends up putting the cursor in the wrong location.

You can verify this by changing to a directory with a longer printed representation: if you `cd /tmp`, then the cursor will be out of place by 4 columns (the length of `/tmp`) instead of 1 (the length of `~`).

---

Also, you can usually use `%~` instead of `${PWD/#$HOME/~}` to include the current working directory. Accordingly, if that was your only substitution, you could then turn off `PROMPT_SUBST`.

Also, with `${PWD/#$HOME/~}`, you'd have problem if `$PWD` contains `%` or control characters. It's best not to have uncontrolled data in the contents of `$PROMPT` if possible, and if that can't be avoided, you'd want to do some escaping so that it still makes sense as a prompt string.