# zsh/Prezto: difficulties with right prompt alignment

Tags: zsh, prompt

This may be stupidly simple, but...

I am trying to make my own prompt for [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto). I have been using numerous prompts for reference (I can post a list if necessary). My RPROMPT and cursor are refusing to align correctly.

I have done lots of Googling, and have found solutions such as [zsh prompt not escaped properly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50123/zsh-prompt-not-escaped-properly) and [ZSH RPROMPT weird space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049870/zsh-rprompt-weird-space). I have been through my code over and over again, making sure all literal escape sequences are surrounded by `%{ ... %}` and anything that takes up space is not. I have also used [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to check for other kinds of errors.

I suspect it has something to do with `prompt_segment` or `prompt_end`, because the misalignment occurs both when I enter a git branch and when log in as root (see screenshots).

I've been working on this for <strike>hours</strike><strike>DAYS</strike>**WEEKS**, and it's driving me nutsy!!

The code is way too long to paste here, but is available on [github](https://github.com/skittleys/prezto/blob/master/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_skittleys_setup). Screenshots are available in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/skittleys/abaf260fa32bf7cb33c2).